# How to use new memory optimized instances (R3) via AWS Opsworks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

I would like to know how to use the new memory optimized instances?

Currently AWS opsworks only allows to select the old generation of memory instances.

http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/04/10/r3-announcing-the-next-generation-of-amazon-ec2-memory-optimized-instances/

Thanks in advance.

**SOLUTION**

from the CLI:

```
$ aws opsworks --region us-east-1  create-instance --stack-id [ID] --layer-ids [ID] --instance-type r3.large --os "Ubuntu 12.04 LTS" --availability-zone "us-east-1a" --auto-scaling-type "timer" --hostname [hostname]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Until AWS adds this themselves, we can't manually provision and use the instances. Your only hope maybe to approach your SA or any contacts in AWS customer support and ask them to add support for these.

You maybe able to get good support for these in the AWS-Forums :https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=153

Comment: Thanks, I contacted support.